Are the humans in "Rebel Moon" originally from Earth, like in "Warhammer 40K"?
Throughout the Rebel Moon films, we hear the term “Motherworld” being used, but the word “Earth” doesn’t seem to come up.
The opening narration in Rebel Moon - Part One: A Child of Fire mentions that:

On the Motherworld, one thousand kings ruled unchallenged in succession. But in the royal bloodline’s lust for power, they consumed everything upon their planet. The Realm marched its armies into the vastness of space, conquering everything in its path.

According to the Rebel Moon wiki, “Motherworld” refers to a collection of planets where the Imperium is headquartered, primarily the planet Moa. Interestingly, I don’t recall Moa being mentioned by name in Rebel Moon 1 or 2. Given the whole “consumed everything upon their planet” bit, humans might have depleted Earth before moving to Moa.
At one point, the Mechanicas Militarium soldier robot JC-1435 (aka Jimmy) says something about trusting Princess Issa to “bring us home.” Could “home” be a reference to Earth?
Are the humans in Rebel Moon from Earth, similar to the Warhammer 40K universe, where humanity originated on Terra (Earth)? (There are quite a few parallels between Rebel Moon and Warhammer 40K.) Or is this more of a Star Wars situation, where humans come from a completely different galaxy far, far away?

Moa definitely isn't Earth; https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/rebel-moon/images/1/14/Moa.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20240423213407

The city of Toa on Aris' (unnamed) home world had a history that stretched back "hundreds of thousands of years"

Lol. Snyder is so full of himself it's unbelievable; "“At one point in the [cancelled Evil Dead TV] show, they go through a portal into another dimension, and there are characters in that other dimension that they come across,” Snyder continues. “In Rebel Moon, they’re in this bar, and one of the aliens is one of the characters from the animatic. So it’s definitely a shared universe.” - https://www.ign.com/articles/rebel-moon-part-one-a-child-of-fire-ending-explained
